# SUMIFS with horizontal range and column header Excel formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Here is a picture to visualize what I want:

[image]

I'm basically trying to sum each row separately based on the value in column A.

I tried with:

```
=SUMIFS(A1:D4,A1:A4,F1)
```

And obtain `#Num`

Because it's based on header values.
I tried to transpose the data range also without luck.

Is there a smart way of doing this insted of summing a row at a time?

I'm trying to avoid range command, where `ctrl`+`shift`+`enter` must be used to obtain a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `F2` either try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A:$A=F1)*$B:$D)
```

Or:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A1:$A4=F1)*$B1:$D4)
```

Where the specific range references would impact your performance way less! Drag right.

Comment: Thank you, this was what I wanted.